# CA-signed Certificate: What URL (Common Name)

Tags: authentication, authorization, tls, api-client-certificate

I'm trying to set up mutual authentication with a third-party. I want to create a new CA signed certificate but I don't know what URL I should use. Testing from our sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some RND and POC, i came to know that the CN name in CSR could be any valid domain name preferably your company name and once you get your certificate you can use it in all your salesforce instances.